# How to pass parameter --cert and --key with CURL PHP?

Tags: php, curl, ssl

```
    $ch = curl_init("www.example.com/curl.php?option=test");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);       
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $output;
```

How can i add for this parameter --cert and --key?

If i use curl in console then i can:

> curl -k --cert new.crt --key new.key
>   https://example.com/curl.php?option=test

but how can i use this in PHP code?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, 'new.crt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, 'new.key');
```

Comment: I am getting ```cURL Error #": "could not load PEM client certificate, OpenSSL error error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory, (no key found, wrong pass phrase, or wrong file format?)```